# ImageJ how to set stiky angles for line tool?

Tags: imagej

When using Line tool if I hold shift key it will "stick" line angle to 45 degrees. Is there a way to make it 15 degrees? I checked out all the options but I'm not finding it.

For my theses I'm measuring capabilities of some printer. I want to check how much printed lines bleed in the paper and deform in relationship to angle of those lines. Lines are positioned in the circle pattern with 15 degree distance.

[image]

What I would like to do is to measure width of those lines. The easiest way would be if I could do it with line tool only if I could set those "sticky" angles.

[image]

If you see better solution to my problem please feel free to tell. Please bear in mind that I'm basic user, and I don't have much experience with this program, and I don't know how to program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming Q&A site, so this question is pretty much off-topic here. Please consider asking it on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) instead. In this case, please also disclose that you're cross-posting by adding a link to this question here.

Comment: Tank you for pointing me in right direction.